# Track Simple Tap Gesture on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gesture

I am using a ViewPager. When I am tapping or touching the ViewPager then I want a layout at bottom to get Visible.

Problem : I am not able to Track the Tap or Touch Event on the ViewPager.

The below image can help to understand my problem.

[image]

Comment: Your image isn't able to see.

Comment: Plz check the Link Again ... I have modified the Link

Comment: I don't understand what do you want, you just linked me a FaceBook profile

Comment: Just modified the link... plz click LINK TO IMAGE again...

Answer (score 0):

You could add an on tap listener to the image itself and the activity could implement an interface and act as a listener. For example, you could have the interface:

```
public interface IViewPagerOnImageTapListener {
    public void onImageTap(int position);
}
```

When clicking on the image view you could do something like this:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(   ) {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onImageTap(position);
    }
});
```

And the activity containing you pager would implement the listener method:

```
@Override
public void onImageTap(int position) {
    // show/hide your overlay layout and do whantever you
    // want with the position (highlight the current item
    // for example)
    LinearLayout hiddenLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
    if (hiddenLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Also, you should somehow pass your activity in such a way that it's available as a listener in your adapter class or wherever you set the on tap listener on the image view.